Bluetooth(BLE) ACL_CONNECTED broadcast not coming in some devices with ble version 5.2
I'm working with android ble, I'm facing one issue where I've to reconnect with the server and show status on app when the client device was already paired or server present in bonded list and moved out of range and comes back.
I saw in most of the phones when I go outside the range and come back, I get the broadcast from a system that it got connected, and we trigger connectivity and show the status on the app;
But some devices don't send this broadcast and, upon retries, give a 133 GATT error.
val filter = IntentFilter().apply {
    addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
    addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)
    addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)
    addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)
    addAction(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)
    addAction(Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED)
}
registerReceiver(BleBroadCastReceiver, filter)

Our logic is retry infinite with a 200ms delay, and if we get this 133 GATT Error, we try 3 times with a 1-second delay, then stop reconnection and wait for the trigger point from the system.
Samsung Galaxy S20 FE gives every time Master clock accuracy = 1  ble version 5.0
Xiaomi M11X gives every time but delayed Master clock accuracy = 5  ble version  5.1
Oneplus Nord 2 5G not giving broadcast: ble version 5.2
autoconnect as false
Can you help me find out why I don't get callbacks or system broadcasts ?
In all those devices I get broadcast for turning on/off Bluetooth but not for auto reconnect.
object BleBroadCastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(
                "BleBroadcast",
                "OnRecieve BleBroadCastReceiver $intent"
            )
        }
    }
}

Thank you

Did you get a disconnected notification when go outside of the rage? The problem can be that the system still keeps the connection open. Also, this can be a problem with specific OEM.

Yes we get proper disconnection as we go out of range

First of all, the Bluetooth version here is irrelevant.
My tip is to not use the broadcasts for connectivity status but instead use the Gatt callback's onConnectionStateChange method to detect this.
Use the autoConnect parameter set to true to connect without timeout and additionally automatically reconnect whenever the device disconnects, until you call disconnect()/close() or Bluetooth is turned off/restarted. Then use Bluetooth broadcasts to detect when Bluetooth is (re)started and at this point recreate your Gatt connection if desired.
You can have a foreground service running in your process to avoid it getting killed by the system.

Yeah the issue is we don't get that broadcast in some devices

You mean you don't get the Bluetooth on/off broadcast when Bluetooth is turned on/off?

We get for on/off, but we are not getting for auto reconnection situation is I pull the airpods and my device auto detects and connects this send ACL_CONNECTED broadcast. This broadcast we are not getting on some phone

Hence why I suggested to use onConnectionStateChange instead.
